# Capistrano deploy fails with rbenv error - when using rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rvm, capistrano, rbenv

I have a very basic capistrano deploy that is currently failing when installing my gem bundle with a very strange error:

```
deployer@xxxxx:~/apps/xxxxx/releases/20150108141101$ ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.1.2 do bundle install --binstubs /home/deployer/apps/xxxxx/shared/bin --path /home/deployer/apps/xxxxx/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment
rbenv: version `2.1.2' is not installed
rbenv: version `2.1.2' is not installed
```

As you can see I'm using rvm, I have no idea why this is happenening.

How can I solve this problem? I couldn't find any documentation on how to completely remove rbenv from my environment, does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Please post your `Gemfile` and `config/deploy.rb` and `Capfile`.

Comment: isnt rbenv installed on your server?